# I am creating a simple database that controls my company's stock

Tags: sql, excel, stock

We have already have a CRM software but it doesn't have stock control ability.

I am thinking to create another database from central SQL Server which has a table of list of product, price, quantity and other information.

In addition, we want to generate a monthly, quarterly and annual report of our stock.

So I am thinking to create a table monthly named as e.g. 201308, 201309.. 201312.. 201405....
Every time when I need to do reporting, I can consolidate multiple tables into a pivot table in excel to do some analysis.

Basically, this is my idea. I don't know the best practice is in this scenario.

Can anyone give me some advices?

Comment: Ah.. inventory, thought you meant stock, and wondered how I could get a database to control my stock.. :(
Don't create monthly tables, just include the year/month field in your table and query that.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into materialized views of your data structure.  Save off the snapshots each month in the format of your choice for reporting purposes.  This would give you a performance boost while maintaining the data structure you desire.

Comment: I see. Thank you. But I think I just create a time related column and work from there.